# Why does mat-slide-toggle not work when we use a custom directive to send it into the reusable generic component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive, slidetoggle

Here is the link of POC on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-stry4y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

In above POC I have `app` component as a root component, `app-expansion-panel` component as a reusable generic component and `custom-expansion-panel` directive as a custom directive. In `app.component.html` I used `app-expansion-panel` component and in that component I passed mat-slide-toggle using `custom-expansion-panel` directive. But somehow it is not working.

mat-slide-toggle should work properly.

Comment: i may be on to something, i noticed the mat slide toggle doesn't take mouse click events. I think you have to catch the clicks events inside your expansion panel, and then simulate it with your directive. Still trying to find how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding a method, and declaring the array inside that same method, so this is what is happening.

- Every time change detection runs getFeaturesExpansionPanelData is called.
- A new instance of featureExpansionPanelData is created when getFeaturesExpansionPanelData is called, this changes the value of panelData in AppExpansionPanelComponent after the view has been initialised, which is messing up the mat-sliders.

These are few easy solutions to the problem

1. Declare featureExpansionPanelData in the constructor

```js
constructor(){
  this.featureExpansionPanelData = [
    {
      label: 'Name',
      value: 'sample name',
      injected: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'Enabled',
      value: '',
      injected: true,
    },
  ];
}

getFeaturesExpansionPanelData() {
  return this.featureExpansionPanelData;
}
```

2. Declare featureExpansionPanelData in the constructor and pass featureExpansionPanelData directly

```js
constructor(){
  this.featureExpansionPanelData = [
    {
      label: 'Name',
      value: 'sample name',
      injected: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'Enabled',
      value: '',
      injected: true,
    },
  ];
}
```

```html
<app-expansion-panel
  [panelDataInput]="featureExpansionPanelData"
  panelTitle="{{ name }}"
>
```

3. Use an input setter and add a condition in there so that panelData value does not get changed

```js
panelData: KeyValueAttributes[] = [];
@Input()
set panelDataInput(value) {
  if (this.panelData.length === 0) {
    this.panelData = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<app-expansion-panel
  [panelDataInput]="getFeaturesExpansionPanelData()"
  panelTitle="{{ name }}"
>
```